# How to Repeat a function every Hour in Android Studio using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, repeat

I want to repeat a function( or any action ) every one Hour ( for example ) even if the app is not running.

Comment: A question of this type should also include attempts to resolve the problem by oneself and why that attempt did not work. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i tied many codes and no of them has work, why i will put a wrong code i want just a new way a new idea

Comment: what you are saying is "I do not understand what the code I try to use do". So maybe you should go back step or two and step up your basics?

Comment: Yes, i should do that but i'm not talking about loops brother !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a demo project so you can take a look at it :

https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/BroadcastReceiverAndAlarmManagerInKotlin

---

You first have to create a [`BroadcastReceiver`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver), and then using [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) you can decide the interval of time you want to be called.

Create a `BroadcastReceiver` you can do it as follows :

```
val broadCastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
     override fun onReceive(contxt: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
         toast("This toast will be shown every X minutes")
     }
}
```

And then you have this method to start the job :

```
val mIntent = Intent(context, broadCastReceiver)

val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, mIntent, 0)
val mAlarmManager = context
    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
    CHANGETOYOURDESIREDSECONDS, mPendingIntent
)
```

And then you'll be able to see the Toast even if the app is closed.

### Edit

You can register your `BroadcastReceiver` using `context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter("something"))`
and then adding to the `mIntent` and action for "something".

If you don't like this way, you can create a new class named `MyReceiver` that extends `BradcastReceiver` as follows :

```
class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"This toast will be shown every X minutes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And then start the alarm doing this :

val mIntent = Intent(this, MyReceiver::class.java)

```
val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        val mAlarmManager = this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            WHATEVERYOUWANT, mPendingIntent
        )
```

**Note: By default is set to 60000**

> Value will be forced up to 60000 as of Android 5.1; don't rely on this to be exact

Comment: there is a problem in this line : val mIntent = Intent(context, broadCastReceiver)
i use  val mIntent = Intent(this, broadCastReceiver) but still the same problem

Comment: Please, check my repository, you have to add the receiver to manifest.xml

Comment: That's another quesiton @WIKOSO, and no, it does not, you have to code a little bit to produce this issue, if you want create a different quesiton explainin what you've tried and what you want to achieve and I can take a look

Comment: this method works fine in the Emulator but it is not working in real devices, what's wrong?

Comment: there is not an error just the Toast it does not run when i use a real device

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AndroidX(JetPack) library then concider to use [Workmanager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Simple example:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    static final String TAG = "workmng";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WorkerResult doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: start");

       //Do your job here

        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: end");

       return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And start like this, to do your job each hour :

```
PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .build();
```

Add in app gradle file:

```
dependencies {
def work_version = 2.0.0

// (Java only)
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
}
```

Comment: This is not Kotlin.

Comment: implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$work_version"  - for Kotlin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396123/how-to-repeat-an-action-everyday-in-android-studio