# How to repeat an action every day in an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-alarms, periodicity

I want to repeat an action every day; it must continue working even if the app is not running or the device has been restarted (rebooted).
In my code I'm trying to show a TOAST message every 1 minute (as a test); it's working fine in the emulator but on a real device it doesn't work( i tried to do some changes to fixed as i see in some answers but still the same thing)

**MyReceiver**

```
class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private val channelId = "com.medanis.hikamwahimam"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.i("TAG","/////////////////// SHOW NOTIFICATION NOW //////////////////////")
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round))
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...")
            .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("Much longer text that cannot fit one line...Much longer text that cannot fit one line..."))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
            notify(12345, builder.build()) }
        Toast.makeText(context,"This toast will be shown every X minutes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mAlarmManager : AlarmManager? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
//        showNotification()

        val mIntent = Intent(this, MyReceiver::class.java)

        val mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        mAlarmManager = this
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        mAlarmManager!!.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            60000, mPendingIntent
        )
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

> **The Issues are :**
>
> 1/- This code does not work with REAL DEVICE.
>
> 2/- This code does not work if the user restart his device.

*A sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/Aniskonig/My-Periodic-App)* (i had made some changes as my friend had suggested but still the same errors)

Comment: You should consider using the WorkManager library as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50357066/2280156). You can learn more at [the tutorial](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/recurring-work) on the official site.

Comment: can you give a sample to the idea in github please !

Answer (score 1):

> 1/- This code does not work with REAL DEVICE.

I've downloaded your project, run on my device and it works, it shows the `Toast` when I click start, and every minute is showing.

I recommend you to take a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739669/android-alarmmanager-not-working-on-some-devices-when-the-app-is-closed/39739886)

> 2/- This code does not work if the user restart his device.

If you want to restart your `BroadcastReceiver` once the device is rebooted or shut downed, you may want to add this code :

Add this in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Create another `receiver` in `manifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And then create a `BroadcastReceiver` as you did previously for showing the `Toast`

```
class BootCompletedIntentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" == intent.action) {
          //Start your old broadcastreceiver
        }
    }
}
```

For more information you can take a look at this [`post`](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-start-android-service-automatically-at-boot-time/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please add your modification to my code and push it to the github project

Comment: i made some changes in the code as i understand but still the same issues please check it again ( my device API is 24 )

Comment: sometimes device block boot broadcast. Go to settings -> battery -> your app and watch if there is toogle to enable receive boot

Comment: Do what Nikolay said @WIKOSO

Comment: i have the same problem @Skizo-ozᴉʞS i tried all things above but nothing has changed ( in the first time i was trying the app on my phone " Condor M1 " now i had tried with " Samsung " and still the same thing) please go back to my code on github, check it and try it with your device

Comment: HEEELp me please